# Search by tag is inconsistent between SO and Unix&LInux?

Tags: discussion, tags

I have encountered a weird issue. I was interested to find all question tagged `awk` in *SO*, but when I done this, by entering `[awk]` in the search bar, I got no results but only brief explanation on `awk` topic. However, when I click on *Newest* tab, I can see the questions. In *Unix&Linux*, the behavior seems to be different. When I search by tag there, I can see all the related questions instantly.

Comment: I can't reproduce this behavior. The pages I get on both sites are *identical*: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/awk) and [Unix/Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/awk)

Comment: @TheEstablishment For some fuzzy definition of "identical"

Comment: @Michael In that I see the same sorts of things. Obviously the site styles are different, but I gave the guy enough credit that he's not asking about that...

Comment: What are you clicked on before you click the *Newest* tab?

Comment: Hi guys. Thank you for your comments. Of course I didn't mean the slightly different layout of the sites. This behavior was appearing few times I tried to perform such search in past. However after clicking on the _Newest_ tab (I never tried it before today, minute before asking this question here), both sites seems to remember that and switch there automatically now. Previously, the only thing that I had on _SO_, is the short explanation which appears at the top of the screen, before the actual questions..